# Деплой Static Nuxt project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Скажите, пожалуйста, сделал landing page для бизнеса на Nuxt, теперь не знаю как это все положить на хостинг. Могу положить на Netlify, но мне нужно с красивым доменом и чтобы работала форма обратной связи(как это сделать еще в раздумьях).

nuxt.config:
Rendering: server-side
Target: static

Demo: https://new-start.netlify.app/
Source: https://github.com/PolyakovDen/test2

Comment: домен можно и на netlify настроить: https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/custom-domains/

Comment: Уже прочел, спасибо) А как быть с отправкой формы? Хочу чтобы данные с формы шли ко мне на е-мейл

Comment: можно каким-нибудь сервисом воспользоваться